# Single time use Jwt Token for email verification in asp.net core with angular 6

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core, jwt

I, am using jwt token for one time email verification.

Here is the c# code to generate jwt token

```
public string OneTimeTokenGenerationForVerification(string userName, int expireTime, string secretToken)
        {
            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var key = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(secretToken);
            var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userName)
                }),
                Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(expireTime),
                SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(key), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
            };
            var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
            return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
        }
```

In the angular side. I, am verifying either the token is expire or not using the below code.

```
public jwtTokenValidation(token : string) : boolean {
        let jwtHelper: JwtHelperService = new JwtHelperService();
        if (token != null) {
            // Check whether the token is expired and return true or false
            return !jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(token);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

The above method will return false if the token is expire. Since, I, have set the expiration hour as 2. So, the token get expire after 2 hour. But, when user gets navigate from email url it validate the email for first time. This is working for me.

Now, when user navigate again the link should not work. How, can I, restrict the user for one time email verification or is their any way to create one time use jwt token from asp.net core.

Answer (score 0):

Well , it's possible to do that . But it is not suggested .

A plain `JWT` token is usually stored on client side, and the server will just validate it when it receives a `JWT` token . When validating the  `JWT` token , the server is considered to be somehow "stateless" . They just validate the signature, issuer, audience, lifetime, and so on .

So if we want to a one-time token , we have to **maintain a state on server side** to prevent [replay attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replay_attack) by the client side . In other words , we'll have a state associated with the `JWT` token , thus we can trigger a delegate to determine whether the token has been consumed when receiveing or validating the `JWT` token .  For example , we can use a [`OnMessageReceived`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.jwtbearer.jwtbearerevents.onmessagereceived?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Authentication_JwtBearer_JwtBearerEvents_OnMessageReceived) to do that :

```
services.AddAuthentication()
.AddJwtBearer(options =>{
    // options.TokenValidationParameters=  ...

    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents() {
        OnMessageReceived= async (context) => {
            var tokenService = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IOneTimeOnlyJwtTokenService>();
            if (context.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("Authorization") ){
                var header = context.Request.Headers["Authorization"].FirstOrDefault();
                if (header.StartsWith("Bearer",StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)){
                    var token = header.Substring("Bearer".Length).Trim();
                    context.Token = token;
                }
            }
            if (context.Token == null) {
                return;
            }
            if (await tokenService.HasBeenConsumed(context.Token))
            {
                context.Fail("not a valid token");
            }
            else {
                await tokenService.InvalidateToken(context.Token);
            }
        }
    };
});
```

The `IOneTimeOnlyJwtTokenService` is a dummy service helps to deal with token generation and token invalidate :

```
public interface IOneTimeOnlyJwtTokenService
{
    Task<string> BuildToken(string name, int? expires);
    Task<bool> HasBeenConsumed(string token);
    Task InvalidateToken(string token);
}
```

Here's an implementation :

```
public class JwtTokenService : IOneTimeOnlyJwtTokenService
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;


    public JwtTokenService(IConfiguration config )
    {
        _config = config;

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Builds the token used for authentication
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="email"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task<string> BuildToken(string userName,int? expireTime)
    {
        var claims = new[] {
            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, userName),
        };

        var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_config["Jwt:Key"]));
        var sign= new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

        var expiredAt = expireTime != null ?
            DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours((int)expireTime) :
            DateTime.Now.AddHours(int.Parse(_config["Jwt:ExpireTime"]));

        var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
        {
            Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(claims) ,
            Expires = expiredAt,
            Issuer = _config["Jwt:Issuer"],
            Audience = _config["Jwt:Audience"],
            SigningCredentials = sign,
        };

        var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
        var token= tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
        var tokenString=tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
        await this.RegisterToken(tokenString);
        return tokenString;
    }

    private async Task RegisterToken(string token) 
    {
        // register token 
    }

    public async Task<bool> HasBeenConsumed(string token) 
    {
        // check the state of token
    }

    public async Task InvalidateToken(string token) 
    {
         // persist the invalid state of token
    }

}
```

Ok , it is certain that it works . But if in that case , the delegate will be invoked every time we have a message received. There's a similar problem with the [`OnTokenValidated`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.authentication.jwtbearer.jwtbearerevents.ontokenvalidated?view=aspnetcore-2.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Authentication_JwtBearer_JwtBearerEvents_OnTokenValidated) event.

Lastly , although it is possible to do that , I suggest you should simply store the token with a `expiredAt` and `invalid` on database , and validate it by filter , model binding  , or even manually  .

Comment: Can you tell me the best way to create and validate token in asp.net core with angular 6 app.

Comment: @SanJaisy could you tell us what's the scenario you would like to use the OneTimeOnlyToken ?

Comment: A user register to website. Then he/she receive an email. When he/she navigate through the link email confirmation need to be done. When they click again to the link the link should expire.

Comment: @SanJaisy if you have only one place to validate the `token` , simply store the token with a "HasBeenConsumed" and validate it by action filter or manually .

Comment: @SanJaisy The way to validate the "HasBeenConsumed" and token are exactly the same as what I posted in the  answer .

Comment: Is it good to use jwt for email verification or any other token creation ?? If yes how can I create token

Comment: @SanJaisy No. Since people will visit the email with another browser , in that case you have no jwt token received

Comment: Can you tell me ... How can I create token in asp.net core. Without jwt

Comment: @SanJaisy A token is more than a string for the client . If you want to create a `jwt` token that can be used as one-time-only , you could simply save the token and an associated `HasBeenConsumed` to database.  However , don't use the jwt token validation  to validate the `HasBeenConsumed` , that's overkill . Simply use a filter or service to do that .

Comment: @SanJaisy Create a table named as `registeration` in database , or if you use the Asp.Net Identity , simply add a claim named as `EmailConfirmed` . Add a claim of `EmailConfirmed=false` when there's a user registered , and set the `EmailConfirmed=true` when validated .

Comment: Thank you that sounds good. I can use claim. But how do I create token in asp.net core. Since I don't want to use JWT for email verification

Comment: @SanJaisy I'm afraid you aren't gonna to need a "token" .1.  A plain GUID will be ok . You can associate the GUID with a user in database .  Every time you need verify the user's email , simpy query the db and find the user , set the claim as `EmailConfirmed=true`. 2. Or if you do like `JWT`, you can simply pass it by querystring `token={JWT_TOKEN}` , thus you can pass it accross the email , but you need to use `OnMessageReceived` event to get the token from querystring .

Comment: @SanJaisy if you choose plain 1 , don't forget to ask the user to submit his username on the page .